# Open file that consist commas powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a code:

```
Powershell_ISE "C:\1\ab,cd,fg.ps1"
```

In this code Powershell_ISE wants open 3 files insted 1. How open file C:\1\ab,cd,fg.ps1 without renaming file.

Comment: This work from CMD window `powershell_ise \"te,st.ps1\"`.

Comment: Yes, this resolves problem. Thanks. Is there are any methods to resolve this issue using only powershell? I'm disappointed if hasn't.

Comment: `powershell_ise '\"te,st.ps1\"'`

Comment: Excellent! That's what i need. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This code resolve my problem:

```
powershell_ise '\"C:\1\ab,cd,fg.ps1\"'
```

Comment: When path to file have spaces, this code don't work.